# Purpose of this capacitor?

Tags: operational-amplifier

What is the purpose of the C2 capacitor in the feedback loop?

What is the time-constant of the R4/R5/R6/C2 net?

[image: opamp schematic]

This is for a pH-probe.

[Source](http://image.dfrobot.com/image/data/SEN0161/pH%20meter%20V1.0%20SCH.pdf)

Comment: For high frequencies C2 has a low impedance, that will **short** the output and - input of U1. It will then behave as a **voltage buffer** (gain = 1) for high frequencies. For low frequencies R4, R5 and R6 determine the gain.

Comment: so, it's an unity buffer for low frequencies and null gain for higher frequencies? the time constant of the filter isn't (C2 x (R4+R5))? why do you think it depends on R6 too?

Comment: *it's an unity buffer for low frequencies and null gain for higher frequencies?* No unity gain (gain = 1) for **high** frequencies and gain > 1 for low frequencies. "null gain" doesn't mean anything. gain = 0 means that nothing comes out, whatever the input signal. If you want the actual transition frequency, do the analysis yourself, you'd have to choose a position for R5 as it is a potmeter. Do the analysis and see how the value of R6 matters.

Comment: I was hoping you'd link not only to the original schematic (which you really presented well in your question, but to the context, i.e. the project in which it's used

Comment: yes it depends on R5 position, but not on R6, I'd rather say the time constant is C2 x (R4+R5pos)

Comment: no worry, I added the link in the question, it's from a pH probe module for Arduino!

Comment: huh, as far as I see it's still the link to the schematic only, no link to the whole project (which would be far more interesting, because it would tell us what you do with the signal that comes out).

Comment: R6 is part of the feedback network and therefore influences the impedance as seen from C2 and that means the crossover frequency depends also on R6. What if we made R6 10 Mohm, what would the transfer of the circuit be? But please feel free to do a proper analysis and **prove** that R6 does not matter and that I know nothing :-) (I'm experienced at this so I already have analysed such circuits many times before so I **know** what the answer is going to be.)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie hm, I'm really confused about why the designer of that circuit decided to put a RC low-pass in series with a 200 MΩ source. Do you have an insight into that?

Comment: you are right, there is a voltage divider with the ground considering R6. Could you give the time constant in that case... please?

Comment: @Vinlar does it really matter? Your input RC time constant considering your source series resistance is > 1s...

Comment: a pH electrode has about 1s response time. But the signal is noisy and needs a 10Hz lowpass (or 15Hz). - I did the experiment with and without.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes it's important at least for my education to find the C2 net constant value!

Comment: from here:  https://youtu.be/gEeF8sEQTEc?t=579
cutoff is 1/(2*PI*R4*R5pos*C2)

Answer (score 2):

C2's purpose is providing negative feedback for higher-frequency signals, thereby attenuating them.

In other words, U1's configuration works as an active low-pass filter. Not by any means a steep one.

I have several problems with the shown schematic, though. They range from aesthetic (GND should always point downwards, full stop) to the functional (the input R1/C1 is a 15Hz wide Low-pass filter. What do the other stages do?) to the component choice (why use an offset-nullable, strobable high-bandwidth opamp, and then use none of the features nor more than 15 Hz of the bandwidth? The extreme input impedance means higher noise than necessary in this configuration; why a JFET as the second stage? Why are the used opamps more than 40 years old? Is this a 1970's design? Do the restrictions that led to that design still apply?). It's always good to evaluate the quality of your circuit sources.

Comment: I am surprised too about the 4.7M resistor, should be a lower value as input to reduce noise (and higher value cap)

Comment: @Vinlar but that might load whatever you attach there. It really depends on what this circuit is for – which I don't know.

Comment: it's for a pH probe, very high impedance! and an open-source design I found on the web.

Comment: uh, how high is "very high"? Because if it's very high, then R1 might be too **low**, not too *high*.

Comment: less or equal to 200 Mohm

Comment: wat? Then that input stage totally wrecks the measured voltage for quite a while (until C1 is charged, i.e. more than a full second).

Comment: and please **edit** your question to include the link to the original schematic!

Comment: it's not a problem because a pH probe can take a few seconds to reach its final value.

Comment: it's still an unnecessary source of problems, and EMI – You'd normally really just connect your probe to the non-inverting input of a low-noise, low-offset opamp to not burden the sensor, see [analog devices' example](https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/reference-designs/circuit-collections/ltc6078-ph-probe-amplifier.html#cc-overview); as said, these are 1970's components, maybe this was a great circuit for the available technology at the time...

Comment: don't you think it's good to have an input resistor in case there is some problem with probe and avoid frying the opamp? Then if connected directly, there wouldn't have a 15Hz lowpass filter at the opamp input.

Comment: no, it's not good. Use a band-limited opamp instead. Also, cost opamp << cost ph Sensor, so who are you protecting from what?

Comment: (also, when you look at the example link I've commented, you'll notice that such problems are essentially solved by the zener diode on the one side of the pH sensor, and by the internal protection diodes of the opamp on the other; you'd avoid noise amplification by using a unity-gain stable opamp as input stage in a voltage follower fashion, and then you'd have a buffered signal that you could filter much, much steeper than the input RC could.)

Comment: the zener builds a reference so that output voltage of the circuit is always positive.

Comment: yes, but that happens by conducting as much current as needed to keep the voltage at 1.25V. So, if a surge happens, the zener just conducts that current to ground, nothing happens.